# How to display google timeline chart in emberJS app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, google-visualization, ember-data

My app.js file has code like this

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('posts');
  });
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
  timeLineData(posts);
   //return posts;
}
});

function timeLineData(posts) {                                              
                        var flag = 0;
                         var itemarray = [];
                         var jsonarray = posts;
                         if($.isArray(jsonarray)) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i += 1) {  
                          var count = 1;
                          var startDate = jsonarray[i].date;
                          var s_date = startDate.split(" ");
                          var start_date = s_date[0].split("-");
                          for(var j = i+1; j < jsonarray.length; j+=1) {          
                            var endDate = jsonarray[j].date;
                            var e_date = endDate.split(" ");
                            var end_date = e_date[0].split("-");
                            if((start_date[0] <= end_date[0]) || (start_date[1] <= end_date[1]) || (start_date[2] <= end_date[2]) ) {
                             if($.inArray(s_date[0], itemarray) < 0) {
                               itemarray[i] = s_date[0];
                               }
                              if($.inArray(e_date[0], itemarray) < 0) {
                               itemarray[i+1] = e_date[0];
                               }
                               flag = 1;
                               break;                       
                            }           
                            break;
                          }
                         if(flag == 0) {
                          // itemarray[0] = startDate
                         }
                        }

                        for (item = 0; item < itemarray.length; item++) {
                        var filtered_json_array = [];
                            if (itemarray[item] != null) {

                            listDate = itemarray[item].split("-");      


                               for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i += 1) {
                                  var startDate = jsonarray[i].date;
                                  var s_date = startDate.split(" ");
                                  var start_date = s_date[0].split("-");
                                  if((start_date[0] == listDate[0]) && (start_date[1] == listDate[1]) && (start_date[2] == listDate[2])) {
                                  filtered_json_array[i] = jsonarray[i];
                                  }
                               }
                               drawChart(filtered_json_array, listDate, "example3.1");

                            }
                        }
                         }
}

function drawChart(jsonarray, listDate, containerId) {

      var container = document.getElementById(containerId);
      var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

      var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Position' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
      dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    var defaultDateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: "HH:mm"});
            var timearr = [];
            var k = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonarray.length; i += 1) { 
                if (jsonarray[i] != null) { 
                k = k+1;
              var count = 1;
              var startDate = jsonarray[i].date;
              var s_date = startDate.split(" ");
              var start_date = s_date[0].split("-");
              for(var j = i+1; j < jsonarray.length; j+=1) {          
                var endDate = jsonarray[j].date;
                var e_date = endDate.split(" ");
                var end_date = e_date[0].split("-");

                 if(((start_date[0] == listDate[0]) && (start_date[1] == listDate[1]) && (start_date[2] == listDate[2])))   {   

                            if(jsonarray[i].emailId == jsonarray[j].emailId) {
                 dataTable.addRow([jsonarray[i].emailId,jsonarray[i].pageId, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)]);
                 timearr[k-1] = "UserId:-" + jsonarray[i].userId + "\n"+ "target:-" + jsonarray[i].target + "\n" + "SectionName:- " + jsonarray[i].sectionName + "\n" + "assignmentName:-" + jsonarray[i].assignmentName
          + "\n" + "ISBN:-" + jsonarray[i].isbn + "\n" + "CourseName:-" + jsonarray[i].courseName + "\n" + "Ip Address:-" + jsonarray[i].ipaddress;
                 count = 2;
                 break;

                }
              }
            }
        if(count ==1) {
               timearr[k-1] = "UserId:-" + jsonarray[i].userId + "\n"+ "target:-" + jsonarray[i].target + "\n" + "SectionName:- " + jsonarray[i].sectionName + "\n" + "assignmentName:-" + jsonarray[i].assignmentName
          + "\n" + "ISBN:-" + jsonarray[i].isbn + "\n" + "CourseName:-" + jsonarray[i].courseName + "\n" + "Ip Address:-" + jsonarray[i].ipaddress;
               dataTable.addRow([jsonarray[i].emailId, jsonarray[i].pageId, new Date(startDate), addMinutes(new Date(startDate),5)]);       
               }
              }
            }
            defaultDateFormat.format(dataTable,2);
            defaultDateFormat.format(dataTable,3);
    var colors = [];
    var colorMap = {            
            LibraryHome: "Yellow",      
            loginPage: "Blue",
            StudentSectionHome: "Red",
            StudentPerformanceReport: "Purple",
            TimeSpentReport: "Grey",
            CourseFileList: "Pink",
            Ebook: "Brown",
            GroupAssignment: "Orange",
            Logout: "Green"     
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
        colors.push(colorMap[dataTable.getValue(i, 1)]);
    }
              var options = {
                        //scaleType: 'maximized',
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'none'
                },
                timeline: {
            colorByRowLabel: colors,
        },
                hAxis: {
                format: 'HH:mm',
                title: 'Time',
            },
            // avoidOverlappingGridLines: true,
             chartArea:{left:0,top:0,width:"100%",height:"100%"},
             width: "1200",
            };
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    //google.visualization.events.addListener(chart,'onmouseover', usefulHandler);
       google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(event) {
       //$('#example3.1').prop('title',timearr[event.row]);
       document.getElementById(containerId).title = timearr[event.row];
       // alert(event.row);
      });



    }
  var posts =[
    {
        "userId": 0,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:37:08 AM",
        "target": "Logintrack",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "courseId": 0,
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "loginPage"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:43:39 AM",
        "target": "Anilsection11",
        "sectionId": 686086,
        "sectionName": "Anilsection11",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "16598927",
        "courseId": 536101,
        "courseName": "MG1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "StudentSectionHome"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:48:39 AM",
        "target": "LibraryHome",
        "sectionId": 686086,
        "sectionName": "Anilsection11",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "16598927",
        "courseId": 536101,
        "courseName": "MG1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "StudentPerformanceReport"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:59:03 AM",
        "target": "Logout",
        "sectionId": 515578476,
        "sectionName": "Mc Connell section1",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "15562355",
        "courseId": 515578475,
        "courseName": "Economics Mc Conell -1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "Logout"
    },
    {
        "userId": 0,
        "emailId": "student@tricon.com",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:39:08 AM",
        "target": "Logintrack",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "courseId": 0,
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "loginPage"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:49:39 AM",
        "target": "Anilsection11",
        "sectionId": 686086,
        "sectionName": "Anilsection11",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "16598927",
        "courseId": 536101,
        "courseName": "MG1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "StudentSectionHome"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-20 7:55:03 AM",
        "target": "Logout",
        "sectionId": 515578476,
        "sectionName": "Mc Connell section1",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "15562355",
        "courseId": 515578475,
        "courseName": "Economics Mc Conell -1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "Logout"
    },
    {
        "userId": 0,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "date": "2014-09-21 7:37:08 AM",
        "target": "Logintrack",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "courseId": 0,
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "loginPage"
    },

        {
        "userId": 0,
        "emailId": "student@tricon.com",
        "date": "2014-09-21 7:37:08 AM",
        "target": "Logintrack",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "courseId": 0,
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "loginPage"
    },
        {
        "userId": 0,
        "emailId": "student@tricon.com",
        "date": "2014-09-21 7:37:08 AM",
        "target": "Logintrack",
        "sectionId": 0,
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "courseId": 0,
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "TimeSpentReport"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8213,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-21 7:43:39 AM",
        "target": "Anilsection11",
        "sectionId": 686086,
        "sectionName": "Anilsection11",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "16598927",
        "courseId": 536101,
        "courseName": "MG1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "StudentSectionHome"
    },
    {
        "userId": 8298,
        "emailId": "student1@tricon.com",
        "role": "Nil",
        "date": "2014-09-21 8:23:34 AM",
        "target": "Logout",
        "sectionId": 515578476,
        "sectionName": "Mc Connell section1",
        "assignmentId": 0,
        "assignmentName": "Nil",
        "isbn": "15562355",
        "courseId": 515578475,
        "courseName": "Economics Mc Conell -1",
        "ipaddress": "192.168.1.112",
        "pageId": "TimeSpentReport"
    },
];
```

My index .html is like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Ember Starter Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization',
       'version':'1.1','packages':['timeline']}]}"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <div class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
       <a class="brand" href="#">Blogger</a>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li>{{#link-to 'posts'}}Posts{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to 'about'}}About{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="posts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span3">
          <table class='table'>
            <thead>
              <tr><th>Recent Posts</th></tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <div id="example3.1" ></div>
              {{#each model}}
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    {{emailId}} <small class='muted'>clicked {{target}}</small>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              {{/each}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>

        <div class="span9">
          {{outlet}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="about">
    <div class='about'>
      <p>
        Yehuda Katz is a member of the <a href="http://emberjs.com">Ember.js</a>, <a href="http://rubyonrails.org">Ruby on Rails</a>
        and <a href="http://www.jquery.com">jQuery</a> Core Teams; he spends his daytime hours at the startup he founded,
        <a href="http://www.tilde.io">Tilde Inc.</a>.
      </p>

      <p>
        Yehuda is co-author of best-selling <a href="http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=485_176">jQuery in Action</a> and
        <a href="http://affiliate.manning.com/idevaffiliate.php?id=485_145">Rails 3 in Action</a>.
      </p>

      <p>
        He spends most of his time hacking on open source—his main projects, along with others, like <a href="https://github.com/wycats/thor">Thor</a>,
        <a href="http://www.handlebarsjs.com">Handlebars</a> and <a href="https://github.com/carlhuda/janus">Janus</a>—or traveling the world doing evangelism work.
      </p>

      <p>He can be found on Twitter as <a href="http://www.twitter.com/wycats">@wycats</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <div class='about'>
      <p>My name is Tom Dale. I helped create <a href="http://www.emberjs.com/">Ember.js</a>, a JavaScript framework that brings sanity to the web.</p>

      <p>In October of 2011, I co-founded <a href="http://www.tilde.io">Tilde</a> with Yehuda Katz, Leah Silber and Carl Lerche.</p>

      <p>In my spare time I run a cash-for-beer exchange program at many local San Francisco dive bars.</p>
    </div>
  </script>
   <script src="js/libs/jquery-v1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-v1.3.0.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-v1.6.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/0.3.1/showdown.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.1.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <!-- to activate the test runner, add the "?test" query string parameter -->
  <script src="tests/runner.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you see the template wth id post, i don't know how to display google chart in this. 
I can create the div with id in this but how to let googlechart to call drawchart on that. If you see the app.js file, in this i can directly send the json data which can be put in loop and display data, what i want here is i want to pass this data to my function which inside calls google chart drawchart method.but how to let this chart get drwn on that particular div. 
I am totaly new to ember.js, would like some help or idea to get it solved.

Comment: i am recently trying example to display this chart through ember.js framework but not founding any success in it.

Comment: Recreate it in a [JsBin](http://ember.jsbin.com)

Comment: Yeah why is there no JSbin?

Comment: You should create component or view to accomplish it.